# Facebook like toolbar in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook

Hi I want to develop Facebook like toolbar in my asp.net site. How can i develop this.

Can anybody suggest some links for that.

Comment: what toolbar are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should master HTML, CSS and JavaScript for that. There are a lot of resources on the internet to learn each technology.

Comment: Don't forget some kind of data base technology to save preferences.